# Problem with a .sty

Tags: compiling

I am editing a lecture notes in  LaTeX and I have found a lot of errors compiling the .tex file. I suspect that those problems are in the .sty file that shapes the style of the book.
How can I look for errors in the .sty file?

This the code of the .sty file

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{estiluoc}[1999/04/23 v0 extensio]

\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{subfigure}
%algorismes
\RequirePackage{amsmath} %Luis Marco (11-9-2006). Alerta: si ``amsmath'' es carrega després ``programa'' es produeix un error.
\RequirePackage{programa} %El paquet ``programa.sty'' es una adaptació de ``program.sty''

%Coloringos
\RequirePackage[dvips]{color}
\definecolor{blanc}{gray}{1}
\definecolor{gris}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{negre}{gray}{0}
\definecolor{light-gray}{rgb}{0.83,0.83,0.83}
\definecolor{sepia}{rgb}{1,0.93,0.76}

\RequirePackage{colortbl}

%\newcommand\filet{l}
\newcommand{\nroregistre}{PX/XXXXX}
\newcommand\ISBN{ISBN: xx-xxxx-xxx-x}
\newcommand\dipositlegal{Dip\`osit legal: B-x.xxx-xx}

\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{definicio}{Definici\'o} 
\newtheorem{propietat}{Propietat}
\newtheorem{proposicio}{Proposici\'o}
\newtheorem{protocol}{Protocol}
\newtheorem{algorisme}{Algorisme}
\newtheorem{problema}{Problema}
%jaume, 10/04/2002
\newtheorem{rema}{Observaci\'o}
\newenvironment{demo}{\begin{quotation}\small\noindent \textbf{Demostració:}\ }{\ \rule{1mm}{2mm}\normalsize\end{quotation}}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}

% comptadors de llistes
\newcounter{cs}
\stepcounter{cs}
\newcommand{\casos}{\hspace{10mm}\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\fcasos}{\end{itemize}\setcounter{cs}{1}}
\newcommand{\cas}{\item[\textbf{(\alph{cs})}]\ \stepcounter{cs}}

\newcommand{\figcen}[1]
              {\begin{center}
              \setlength{\fboxsep}{4mm}
              #1  \end{center}}       

%jaume, 15/06/2002
%etiqueta exemples i exercicis (substitueix \label)
\newcommand{\etiqexe}[1]{\label{#1}\newcounter{c#1}\setcounter{c#1}{\thenexemple}}

%etiqueta test i resultats destacats (substitueix \label)
\newcommand{\etiqdes}[1]{\label{#1}\newcounter{t#1}\setcounter{t#1}{\thenumres}}

\newcounter{sref}
%referencia \etiqexe
\newcommand{\mref}[1]{\setcounter{sref}{\value{c#1}}\textbf{\arabic{modul}-\arabic{sref}}}

\newcounter{tref}
%referencia \etiqdes
\newcommand{\dref}[1]{\setcounter{tref}{\value{t#1}}\textbf{\arabic{modul}.\arabic{tref}}}

%inicialització comptador respostes
\newcommand{\respini}{\setcounter{numresp}{\thenexemple}}

%Luis Marco, 31-8-2006. Instrucció per a forçar el justificat de l'última línia de text.
\newcommand{\liniaforzada}{\linebreak\vspace{-15.35pt}} 

%Instrucció per a fer servir el tipus semibold en comptes de la negreta. (Lluís Marco. 12-5-2006)
\newcommand{\textsbold}[1]{{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont #1}}

%Distàncies entre les fórmules i el texto
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{22pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{22pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{22pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{22pt}
\setlength{\jot}{15.35pt}% Distància entre fórmules als entorns eqnarray.

%Format de les taules
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} %Addicció d'espai vertical entre les files d'una taula.

%bibliografia en català. 
%Luis Marco. 22-12-2009
\newcommand{\biblio}{
\addcontentsline{toc}{previs}{Bibliografia}
\bibliographystyle{uoctex}
 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\hspace{-14pt}}
 \renewcommand\@bibsetup[1]{}
 \makeatother
\bibliography{bibliografia}}

%Bibliografia en castellà
%Luis Marco. 22-12-2009
\newcommand{\biblioes}{
\addcontentsline{toc}{previs}{Bibliograf\'ia}
\bibliographystyle{uoctex-es}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\hspace{-14pt}}
\renewcommand\@bibsetup[1]{}
\makeatother
\bibliography{bibliografia}}

%Instrucció per a Incidències
\newcommand{\incidencia}[1]{\fbox{\parbox{17cm}{\textcolor[named]{Red}{\textbf{INCIDENCIA. #1}}} }}
\newcommand{\faltafigura}[1]{\fbox{\parbox{17cm}{\textcolor[named]{Red}{\textbf{FALTA FIGURA\vspace{#1}}}}}}


%Instrucció que crea un salt de pàgina per als casos on els recursos al lateral no permeten un resultat òptim en fer servir \newpage. 
%Es pot fer servir com a \paginanueva o \paginanueva[-42pt]
\newcommand{\paginanueva}[1][-22pt]{\newpage\mbox{}\vspace{#1}}

%Instrucció per a crear una pàgina en blanc
\newcommand{\paginablanca}{\newpage\mbox{ }\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}

\endinput
%
%
```

And the beginning of the document is

```latex
\documentclass{uoc-es}
% treure el comentari per a la versio en castella
%\castella


%\usepackage[\CATSP]{babel}
%canviar els comentaris per a la versi\'{o} en castell\`{a}
\usepackage[spanish,catalan]{babel}
%\selectlanguage{catalan}
\selectlanguage{spanish}


\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage{mathstone}%MathStone versión 1.2
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[right,eurosym]{eurofont}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

%local package
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,trees}
% algorismes, conve que sigui el darrer
\usepackage{programa}



\title{\color[gray]{0.5}{Fundamentos de grafos}}
\author{Joaquim Borges\\[4.25pt]  Robert Clarisó\\[4.25pt] Ramon Masi\`{a}\\[4.25pt] Jaume Pujol\\[4.25pt] Josep Rif\`{a}\\[4.25pt] Joan Vancells\\[4.25pt] Merc\`{e} Villanueva}
\newcommand{\credits}{}
\newcommand{\nommodul}{Fundamentos de grafos}
\renewcommand{\nroregistre}{PID_00174686}
%arxiu que incorpora la foto de la portada
%\newcommand{\fotoportada}{./logo-uoc.png}
%\newcommand{\modulEncap}{$\text{ }\bullet$ M\'{o}dulo 2} %M\`{o}dul en l'encap\c{c}alament.
\newcommand{\modulEncap}{}
\newcommand{\modul}{}
\renewcommand{\UOC}{CC-BY-NC-ND}
%local commands

% \hypersetup{
%     pdfauthor = {Joaquim Borges, Ramon Masi\`{a}, Jaume Pujol, Josep
% Rif\`{a}, Joan Vancells, Merc\`{e} Villanueva},
%     pdftitle = {Fundamentos de grafos},
%     pdfsubject = {},
%     pdfkeywords = {},
%     }

%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\textsbold}[1]{{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont #1}}
\newcommand{\lfor}{\linebreak\vspace{-15.35pt}} 
\nofiles


\begin{document}

%\selectlanguage{spanish}

\maketitle


\newpage
\mbox{ }
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

The first errors that I found are

```latex
LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <14> on input line 67.
! Undefined control sequence.
\maketitle ...\titulet \credits \par \nroregistre 
                                                  \par \modul } \par \vfil \...
l.67 \maketitle

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: it is impossible to help given so little information. The error messages (that you have not shown) will tell you what is wrong and on what line the error is detected (which isn't necessarily the line with the error but a good place to start looking)

Comment: You're never loading `\usepackage{estiluoc}`.

Comment: Ohh...thanks a lot. I was so dumb.

Comment: note that if you are using pdflatex (the default system usually) then `\RequirePackage[dvips]{color}` should be `\RequirePackage{color}` as the dvips option forces support for latex+dvips latex system not pdflatex